# Как указать адрес отправителя?

Tags: email, freebsd

На линуксовом сервере команду mail можно запустить с ключом -a и указать адрес отправителя. На сервере с freebsd утилита mail почему-то не понимает такого ключа и не умеет изменять заголовки. Можно ли как-то добавить эту возможность?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

поставь sendEmail это  перловый скрипт он умеет то  что тебе нужно